# Azure vm is very slow

Tags: performance, azure, virtual-machine

I have vm on azure. having Windows Server 2012 R2 and location is west us zone.
When I take RDC of that VM from India. It loads very slowly. Even after RDC, clicks also take time to respond.

I have some applications running on VM which also runs very slow.

Can you please help me with this?

Comment: What size is the VM?

Comment: This isn't a programming question. It should be posted to ServerFault or SuperUser. Further: You've provided no information about what's running, what you've checked regarding CPU usage, or anything else about the VM. Even posting on ServerFault, you'll need to provide more information.

Answer (score -1):

If your location is India then for best results you should create the VM in Southeast Asia zone which is nearest. Please also check the VM size and configure it according to the requirement.

Please also take reference to create VMs in right way:

http://subhashsingh.com/2015/01/creating-windows-10-preview-virtual-machine-from-microsoft-azure-gallery/

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/buckwoody/archive/2013/04/17/creating-a-windows-azure-virtual-machine-the-right-way.aspx

Comment: "Nearest" is not always distance-based, and stating the OP will get best results in a given region is merely speculation. Plus you're making an assumption that network latency is the culprit. We have no idea why there's slowdown on the VM, as the OP has provided no information about it (plus, it's not a programming question).

Comment: Dear, David thanks for making me down, but as per the recommendation people should create in use service in the same region where they want to consume

Answer (score -1):

Use Azure Monitoring Dashboard to see the CPU Percentage and Memory for the VM (VM->Select VM->Monitor Tab), if they have reached above 70-75% consider upgrading the VM to higher version (for more information on VM Sizes see [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-size-specs/)).

If the CPU Percentage/Memory are relatively low (20-30%) then it could be the network bandwidth which is causing the trouble, the only option here could be to upgrade your network bandwidth or deploy the machine in the near by data center (SEA) as suggested below, but this could have an impact on usability if the applications allows users to connect from all corners of globe.

Comment: These are good suggestions to post as comments, to help the OP figure out the problem. But what you posted isn't an answer;  it's a way to start looking for answers. We have no idea why the OP's VM is slow. (Also, best not to answer off-topic questions).