# Git commit works instantaneously but gradle clean build takes almost 5 minutes in intellij. Resynch happens within seconds

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, intellij-idea

I am working with Intellij 2019.3.3 and Gradle 5.1.1.

Gradle clean build takes 5-7 minutes. Gradle sync takes between 15-20 seconds.

This happens only when i use it in my VM though ( Azure Desktop ) . It was much faster in my physical machine.

No difference observed while executing the application.

I have observed that git commits and code check-ins are faster in VM ( Azure Desktop ) .

How can i speed up build in VM ? Why does it take so long ?

Edit 1 : I am building a spring boot application. It is the "bootJar" task that takes time.

Config below :

```
bootJar {
    classifier = 'boot'
    mainClassName = 'com.aaa.bbb.someservice.SomeServiceApplication'
}
```

Comment: VM means shared machine which means it will be slower then physical one, you may try to upgrade cpu or ram and monitor as said in https://stackoverflow.com/a/31962492/175554

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the answers above. The speed improved after I increased Intellij's Stack and Heap Memory inside vmoptions file.

Answer (score 0):

Verify that the VM machine has enough available memory. You can allocate more memory to a Gradle daemon process by specifying `-Xmx` value in `gradle.properties` in your project root directory, for example: `org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2000m`.

Use [Build Scan](https://scans.gradle.com/) to [investigate your Gradle build performance](https://docs.gradle.org/nightly/userguide/performance.html#profiling_with_build_scans) metrics.

Check also other tips from [official Gradle recomendations](https://docs.gradle.org/nightly/userguide/performance.html).

Comment: for my case it is a problem with the bootJar task. It takes 5 minutes. I increased Xmx but didnt make any difference.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're generating a bootJar that contains everything inside it to run standalone, I guess the slowness could be related to I/O of your disk. I'd check if your are using SSD and you have plenty of CPU to run the "packaging".